# How does a UART transmit data if we only need to send 2 bits?

Tags: uart

How does a UART transmit data if we only need to send 2 bits? What would the data frame look like?

Comment: More context needed. What hardware will send the data i.e. through MCU's UART hardware, or through MCU with software-implemented UART?

Comment: For a standard UART: `start | 8 data | stop`, the overhead (non-data bits) is: `(1 + 1) / 10` or 20%. For a 2 bit frame: `start | 2 data | stop`, the overhead is: `(1 + 1) / 4` or 50%. So, even if you _could_ find/create such a UART, I'd follow Neil_UK's second choice and accumulate your bits into 8 bits of data: `start | 2bit,2bit,2bit,2bit | stop`. You might have the S/W do compression of some sort (e.g. RLE, LZW, etc.). If you design your own UART, you can do whatever (e.g. NRZI, 8/10 codepoint ala FibreChannel) rather than start/stop.

Answer (score 12):

It depends whether you mean 'a UART', or 'an easily obtainable UART'.

If you had the freedom to implement your own UART, in an FPGA, or bit-banging an MCU port, then you could implement a 2-bit word. You might transmit a start bit, two data bits, and stop bit.

If you want to use an existing UART design or library, then none AFAIK can be programmed down to a 2 bit word, if the word length is programmable at all.

You then have two simple choices, assuming you're going to use a UART with an 8-bit word.

- Transmit your 2 bits of data with 6 packing bits, that you ignore at the receiver
- Accumulate your data until you have four 2-bit words, pack them into a single 8-bit word, and send that
- and several more complicated choices, involving other numbers of bits packed into or across UART words

Comment: An ordinary UART can do it too, using 8 bits data, mark parity, two stop bits.  Send {0 0 D1 D1 D1 D0 D0 D0}, producing [S 0 0] [D1 D1 D1] [D2 D2 D2] [M T T] which looks very much like a 2 bits data, no parity, 1 stop bit sequence at one-third the baud rate.

Answer (score 5):

You can send two bits in the full frame of 7 or 8 bits; just ignore the bits you are not using and recover the bits you are interested in.

Choose any of the below data bits to use for your two-bit data: -

[image]

Image from [UART explained](https://developer.electricimp.com/resources/uart).

Answer (score 4):

UART works with bytes.

If you want to send only two bits (i.e. from 00 to 11) you still need to send 7 or 8 bits (depending on the configuration), but the least significant bits will be your 2-bit data and the rest will be 0.

For example, if you send 10 (decimal 2) over UART, the bits train will look like this *(assuming a config of no parity, 8-bit data, 1 stop bit)*:

```
STARTB D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 STOPB
0      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: That's true for some definition of byte, even if a byte is typically 8 bits these days. Typically UARTs support 5 to 8 data bits but support also varies up to 9 data bits. The 2 bits could also be encoded to 4 quite different symbols so they don't have to be padded with zeroes.

Comment: What is byte oriented about it? (Except in the obsolete meaning of "byte" as "computer word").  In any case just checking on a current CPU (stm32h7), its built-in UART will do 7-, 8- and 9-bit words.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to send 2 bits in a frame, then you can use any frame size with 2 or more data bits. Likely smallest standard frame size you can find size is 5 data bits. So for simplicity, standard 8-bit frame might be best option as it is universally most supported.

As data frame has more bits than you need, you can encode the 2 bits into four different 8-bit values for improved debugging as human readable text.

The four symbols could just be "1234" or "ABCD" but to add better error detection symbols that have more different than just one or two bit could be used to detect errors better if you want.